# Need help with identifying transformer ratio

Tags: transformer

[image: Transformer]

Does the transformer ratio 240:15 or 240:30? It's a bit confusing

Comment: 15-0-15V. So you can get 30Vrms from it but the centre tap allows 15V as here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 240:30 with secondary centre-tap.

You might find it specified as "primary 240 V, secondary 15-0-15 V" which gives a clearer idea of how the secondary is configured.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it